# Custom Search Box in Community/Napili

Tags: lightning, search, napili

I am trying to use the Napili template (migrating from an APEX page).  Currently we do not have search functionality on that custom page, so the thought was to use Napili and the pre-built templates.  However, there doesn't seem to be a component or even a VF code example that I can use.  Anyone have ideas?  I simply need to look up/display cases for a user then let them click on that return.

Answer (score 1):

You can use forceCommunity:searchInterface to create Custom Search Box. The component can be set as Custom Search from Napili configuration - Theme and change Default search functionality with new Aura component you have created. I have created custom search and it worked fine. Only pain is to show autocomplete which I believe can achieve using CSS/JS.

Please let me know how it goes.